# Why it always report .net core SDK not installed while it already here?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am going to debug my asp.net core project in the windows server 2012R2 while the VSCode reports this.

Then I installed the .net core SDK.

However, the error above comes again.

Well, in the `Programs and Features` of `Control Panel`, it is installed already yet.
[image]

It is so strange that in the Powershell of `dotnet --info`.
[image]

It said that no SDKs were found.

Why it turns out to be this?

And how can I install the .net core SDK correctly?

PS: the computer is an X64 system.

Comment: It looks to me like you've got the x86 version of `dotnet` in your path, but it's the x64 version of the SDK you're expecting to find.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I download the SDK from microsoft official page and it only provides X64 version for me.

Comment: It's available in both (see [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)). I don't think downloading the x86 version is the solution - instead I expect your system path is configured to use `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` instead of `C:\Program Files\dotnet`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I have updated an answer and solve this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I have installed both X86/X64 Runtimes.

After I uninstalled the X86 Runtime, it works.